# How to plot circles with specific radiuses on the contour plot (heat map) with pyplot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a waveform from an ultrasonic sensor, based on the peaks I have calculated the radiuses (object distance from the sensor) and I would like to use matplotlib to plot the radiuses on a colormap to accentuate all the possible locations for objects in the field of view of the sensor- that should result in a colormap that has circles with the calculated radiuses on it so, that the results with a bigger intensity at that radius (value) have a brighter color.

Based on measured radiuses: [  0.      3.434   6.868  10.302]
And values: [1, 5, 1, 3]
This drawing would illustrate what I want (sorry for the bad gimp skills, these are supposed to be circles):

[image]

In real life the colourmap is supposed to be a lot more "fluctuating" with no such perfectly defined narrow circles.

Here's my code that only gives me a blank graph:

```
def plot_2D_heatmap(self, radiuses, values):

    print(radiuses)
    #[  0.      3.434   6.868  10.302]
    print(values)
    #[1, 5, 1, 3]

    #calculate the x and y coordinates in mm for each measured radius and angle
    angles = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 36) #every 10 degrees

    no_of_coordinates = len(radiuses) * len(angles)

    X = []
    Y = []
    Z = np.zeros((no_of_coordinates,no_of_coordinates))

    for r in range(len(radiuses)):
        for a in range(len(angles)):
            x = radiuses[r] * np.cos(angles[a])
            y = radiuses[r] * np.sin(angles[a])

            X.append(x)
            Y.append(y)
            Z[a][r] = values[r]

            '''
            print(r)
            print(a)
            print(values[r])
            '''

    norm = cm.colors.Normalize(vmax=abs(np.array(Z)).max(), vmin=-abs(np.array(Z)).max())


    fig, ax = plt.subplots()


    cset1 = ax.contourf(
       X, Y, Z, 4,
       norm=norm)
    plt.show()
```

And here is some code that produces kind of the result I want, but the circles are "inside out" - the centers should be (0,0) and I feel I shouldn't be doing this so "manually:

```
    print(radiuses)
    #[  0.      3.434   6.868  10.302]
    print(values)
    #[1, 5, 1, 3]

    #calculate the x and y coordinates in mm for each measured radius and angle

    x = np.linspace(-20, 20, 40)
    y = np.linspace(-20, 20, 40)

    X, Y = np.meshgrid(y,x)

    angles = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 360) #every 1 degrees

    no_of_coordinates = len(radiuses) * len(angles)

    Z = np.zeros((40, 40))

    for r in range(len(radiuses)):
        for a in range(len(angles)):
            x = radiuses[r] * np.sin(angles[a])
            y = radiuses[r] * np.cos(angles[a])

            x = round(x)
            y = round(y)

            Z[x][y] = values[r]

    norm = cm.colors.Normalize(vmax=abs(np.array(Z)).max(), vmin=-abs(np.array(Z)).max())


    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    print(X)
    print(Y)
    print(Z)

    cset1 = ax.contourf(
       X, Y, Z, [1, 2],
       norm=norm)
    plt.colorbar(cset1)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `Z` represents the plot but does not use the same coordinates as the plot. In other words, (0, 0) on the plot is actually about `Z[20, 20]`. Key changes when looping through `Z` should be:

```
        x = int(round(x)) + 20
        y = int(round(y)) + 20
```

Just to be clear, I made a few minor changes to your code so that it can run without errors and give what you've shown. In the end, key changes give the following plot, which is hopefully what you want.

[image]